# Personalizar dialogo por defecto de GoogleApiAvailability

Tags: android, diálogo, google-play-services

Buenas, tengo este método que te comprueba si existen los GooglePlayServices en el dispositivo:

```
public static boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Activity activity) {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int status = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
    if(status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(status)) {
            googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, status, 2404).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de modificar ese diálogo por defecto que te crea?

Se que podría yo crear mi propio diálogo pero me gustaría saber si se podría modificar el que te crea por defecto, por ejemplo, cambiarle el texto de información y el texto del botón